# If clause gives back 2 different result

Tags: programming, debugging

I am writing a simple if clause, but keep getting wrong answers, so I ended up writing 2 almost the same if clauses, one giving back correct answer, and the other giving back wrong answer.  Can't figure out the problem.

1.(giving wrong answer)

```
InsertIndex2[x_, list_] := 
   Module[{length, compareResult, middleIndex, newList, newResult, 
    whichResult}, 
    length = Length[list];
   middleIndex = Floor[(length + 1)/2]；
   #Print[middleIndex];
   Print["length=", length];
  If [length == 0,  1, 2]]
```

Input:

```
 c = {}
 d = InsertIndex2[1, c]
```

Output:

```
length = 0
0
```

2. (giving correct answer)

   f = Module[{a},
   a = 0;
   If[a == 0, 1, 2]]

input:

```
e=f
```

output:

```
1
```

Comment: you have a problem with the semicolon after middleIndex. it does not look like a semicolon.

Comment: Also, what is `#Print` intended to be?

Comment: @bob a comment, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

If I remove the syntax errors and irrelevancies from your code

```
InsertIndex2[x_, list_] :=
  Module[{length, middleIndex},
    length = Length[list];
    middleIndex = Floor[(length + 1)/2];
    Print[middleIndex];
    Print["length=", length];
    If[length == 0, 1, 2]]
```

then

```
InsertIndex2[1, {}]
```

gives

[image: results]

which is exactly what you wanted.